# How open Modal Jsp Page in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am using **Spring Mvc** and **Booststrap** in a web application and I would like to display the **editEmployer.jsp** page as a **Popup**. Below is the code:

**Page Index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    "url": "/employeesmanagement/api/employees/listEmplyees'",
    "type": "GET",
    "datatype": 'json',
    "success": function (data) {
        $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
            data: data,  
            columns: [
                {
                    title : 'id',
                    data : 'id'
                }, {
                    title : 'name',
                    data : 'name'
                },
{  
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta)  
                        { return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" role="button" href="/editEmployer/' + data.id+ '">Edit</a>'; }  
                    }
            ]
        });
    }
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="employeesTable" style="width: 100%"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@Transactional
@EnableWebMvc
public class EmployerController {

   @RequestMapping("/editEmployer")
   public String editEmployer(Model model, @RequestParam("id") String id) {
       Employer employer = new Employer();
       Repository repository = new Repository();
       if (id != null) {
           employer = repository.getEmployer(id);
       }

       model.addAttribute("employerModel", employer);
       return "employerForm";
   }

}
```

**Employer page**

```
<html>
<body>

   <form:form action="saveEmployer method="POST" modelAttribute="employerModel">

       <form:hidden path="id" />

       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
               <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
               <td><form:errors path="name"></td>      
           </tr>  
           <tr>
               <td>Email</td>
               <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know we can do it with **Boostrap**, but this method requires to put the code of the page **editEmployer.jsp** in the same page **Index.jsp** .How can we open the **editEmpoloyer.jsp** page like a Popup knowing that it is in a separate page than the **index.jsp** page ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style="display: none;"` to `popupPageDiv` and can show hide using javascript/jquery.

```
<div id="popupPageDiv" style="display: none;">
    <jsp:include page="popup.jsp"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, despite there are no specific examples that address this kind of need for Spring MVC. So just call the action of the controller with Ajax as well as the display of the response in a Bootsrap modal Div .

**Ajax call of the action controller**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function editEmploer(id)
{
    
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/CallOffice/editEmployer",
        data : {id:id},
        contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (response, status, xhr) {
              $('#editEmployerModalContainer').html(response);
              $('#editEmployerModalDiv').modal('show');
            
          },
          error: function (response) {
              alert(response.responseText);
          }
    });  
 
}

</script>
```

**Bootstrap modal div**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editEmployerModalDiv" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editEmployerLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id='editEmployerModalContainer'>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps anyone who is having the same issue.